# Access subform unbound control #Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, subform

I have a subform embedded in my main form as a datasheet. The subform's data gets populated after I select some filtering criteria and click "search" button. Everything works fine except one control I have in this subform. This is an unbound control and I will set its control source in the subform's onLoad event with values input from other controls of my subform. When I first load the main form and before select anything or click "search" button, the subform is displayed with an empty row of record. However, on the column of my unbound control, it shows as "#ERROR" while others are all blank. I know this will work fine after I do the search and my unbound control data gets populated, but is there anyway I can avoid showing the ugly "#ERROR" in my subform?

Part of my code is here.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.text_root_cause_field.ControlSource = "=getLatestRemark([plant], [shipment_no])"

End Sub

Public Function getLatestRemark(plant_code As String, shipment_no As String) As String

Dim db As Database
Dim srRS As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set srRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 root_cause FROM Shipment_Remark" _
                            & " WHERE plant = '" & plant_code & "'" _
                            & " AND shipment_no = '" & shipment_no & "'" _
                            & " ORDER BY update_time DESC", dbOpenDynaset)

If Not srRS Is Nothing Then
    If Not srRS.EOF Then
        getLatestRemark = srRS!root_cause
        srRS.Close
        Set srRS = Nothing
    End If
Else
    getLatestRemark = ""
End If

db.Close
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

These are codes for my subform. text_root_cause_field is the unbound field I am talking about. Its control source depends on two other bound fields - [plant] and [shipment_no]. The field [plant] and [shipment_no], however, are only bound at run time after the user clicks search button in the main form and the subform's record source is set.

Thanks  for the help.

Comment: Couldn't you at least bind it to a valid column even if you're going to change it after a search?

Comment: @HK1 Thanks for the advice. I tried to include an empty column in my subform's recordsource and bind this column to that control. But strangely, that "#ERROR" still shows up...

Comment: Posting your code may help us help you. Can you clarify if the control is bound or unbound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Wayne G. Dunny for his helpful discussion with me. This helps me figure out the problem of my current implementation and a possible solution to it.

Here is the reason for the #ERROR shown in my unbound text box, text_root_cause_field. This text box is bound to a function call in my subform's Load Event with two other fields from my subform's record source as parameters. This will initially give me a value in text_root_cause_field text box because the record source of my subform has been set in the form property to be one of my queries, Shipment_cycle_time.

This works fine until the program hits my main form's Open Event. In the Open Event, I set the subform's record source to be NULL because I do not want to display any data on the form's startup. As the main form's Open Event happens **after** the subform's Load Event, I do not have any field present in the subform any more. So the function which my text_root_cause_field is bound to is retrieving values from two non-existent fields. This gives the #ERROR.

The solution is pretty simple after the cause is figured out. I can include the SQL output of my function to the SQL of my subform's record source. So the subform's record source becomes like

```
SELECT s.*, (SELECT TOP 1 root_cause FROM Shipment_Remark as r 
                            WHERE r.plant = s.plant
                            AND r.shipment_no = s.shipment_no 
                            ORDER BY r.update_time DESC) as root_cause 
          FROM shipment_cycle_time AS s WHERE TRUE
```

In addition to all the fields in shipment_cycle_time query, the other field root_cause is selected from a different table based on the two shipment_cycle_time fields. This is exactly the same as what returns from the function. Instead of using a function, I set the controlsource of the text box text_root_cause_field to root_cause field.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the value in the Form_Load event, why not just check if there are zero records, and if so, then don't set the value - let it be blank.

Comment: I added that check, but still no luck. I believe the error is due to the binding action itself, not the binding result. Please see my code pasted.

Comment: Since the subform record set is populated before the load event I think you should remove the subform record source then in main load event unbind or remove source of text field. Then if record set has records remind or set source.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your idea correctly. If I don't bind the text field in my subform's load event, which is the event in the main form I can use to do the binding?

Comment: You can bind via vba code.. BUT Only If Rs Is populated. I suggest unbind rs and txt in subform as default. Then if rs has records fix your text box

Comment: I have added the following check in my subform's load event. `Private Sub Form_Load()
    
    Debug.Print Me.RecordSource
    
    If Me.RecordSource <> "" Then
        If [plant] <> "" And [shipment_no] <> "" Then
            Me.text_root_cause_field.ControlSource = "=getLatestRemark([plant], [shipment_no])"
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub` However, this time I got the #Name? display in my unbound text field when subform is loaded before RS is populated

Comment: Sorry for delay.. on vacation..  You really need to be able to detect all of the variable conditions that occur and program to handle them. Please correct/confirm my understanding:
1. Problem only happens when NO records on subform? 
2. What is the value of 'Control Source' when you get #Name or #Error?
3. There are no error traps, so without stepping thru the code line by line, you may be misled to source or problem/error.
4. I would place a breakpoint in the code and walk thru, examining values all the way! If I get time, I will try to create your situation.

Comment: I have built your form & subform, but in doing so, I want to know more of the intent you have.
1. Are you expecting to see multiple rows in the subform?
2. Are users allowed to ADD, DELETE OR CHANGE values in subform? Please answer all three.
3. Is the intent with the unbound field just to show the user the latest, or is it to prevent them from changing it?
Depending on your answers, I have a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I would say the problem occurs when there is no RecordSource of the subform. I had set the subform's record source originally in its property, but I have also set its record source to empty in my mainform's open event so no data is shown at first. As the subform's load event happens before main form's open event, my unbound control's control source has already been assigned. But later [plant] and [shipment_no] become invalid reference because I clear the subform's record source in main form's open event. I believe that is the cause of the error.

Comment: Another way I have tried is to bind the control source later at the subform's current event. However, this will cause my subform to refresh and visually "blinks" on screen every time user clicks through records. I do not think this is a good presentation.

Comment: To answer your question, I am expecting to see multiple rows in subform. And I not allow any modification of the data by user except there is a click event I would like to handle when user select one of the fields. Yes, the unbound field is for me to display the latest comment regarding the shipment.

Comment: OK, I now understand. There is one major problem with using the unbound textbox - there is no way to have the textbox with a unique value on each row - all rows will reflect the 'latest' value that you calculate.  Therefore, I suggest that you embed a call to your function inside the query for the subform and bind that to field 'text_root_cause_field'.  The reason for my asking about ADD and Change is if you set the 'Allow Additions' property to NO, then you can avoid the error you were seeing when you had zero records -- but that should not be needed if you bind to query.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? How do I include a function call like "=getLatestRemark([plant], [shipment_no])" in my SQL statement?

Comment: Since your function is already 'Public' and returns a value, in your query add a field that looks like 'getLatestRemark([plant_code], [shipment_no]) As root_cause, ...   
If you look at your query output, you should see the values you want. Now just make sure your field ''text_root_cause_field' is bound to 'root_cause' from the query.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just realized in fact I do not need to call the function getLatestRemark. Instead, I can just build in that select sql inside the sql of my subform's record source. If you don't mind, I will post my current solution here.